# No puedo llamar a un metodo en otro metodo

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio donde primero hay que ordenar los numeros y luego sacar la mediana, el problema es que no se puedo llamar al metodo ordenar, me sale el error *cannot find symbol arreglo=symbol(vec)*.

```
public class Mediana {

    public static double[] ordenar(double[] vec){
    double num=0;
    
       for(int i=0;i<vec.length;i++){
           for(int j=1;j<vec.length-i-1;j++){
                if(vec[j]<vec[j+1]){
                    num=vec[j+1];
                    vec[j+1]=vec[j];
                    vec[j]=num;
               }
            }
     } 
     return vec;
   }
    
    public static double mediana(double[] arreglo){
        arreglo=ordenar(vec);
        int medio=arreglo.length/2;
        double mediana=0;
        if(arreglo.length%2==0){
            mediana= (arreglo[medio-1]+arreglo[medio])/2;
        } else{
            mediana=arreglo[medio];
        }
    return mediana;
    }
}
```

Comment: Tenes un error en la linea ``arreglo=ordenar(vec);`` debería ser ``arreglo=ordenar(arreglo);``

Comment: Eso funcionó, pero no entiendo como funciona eso.

Comment: El problema que te señala @JFrame se dá porque en el ámbito del método `mediana(double[])` no existe la variable `vec`. Por esto, al cambiar `vec` por `arreglo`, que sí existe puesto que es un parámetro del método, te compila el código.

Comment: Gracias por la explicación